# Reference request: Formal Existence for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Is there a formal existence Theorem for coherent sheaves on locally Noetherian Artin Stacks, in the spirit of Grothendieck's Formal GAGA?

Is it available for more general stacks?

Comment: https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/formalgaga.pdf

Comment: @Merlin: That paper (and the paper of Olsson it references) indeed prove a formal GAGA theorem for proper Artin stacks.  But my feeling is that this is not the strongest result possible -- in particular, the properness hypothesis (and even separatedness!) often fail for natural moduli stacks that arise "in nature."  IIRC Jack Hall, David Rydh, and others have some results in the non-proper setting; there is also this paper of Geraschenko and Zureick-Brown: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d818/e8f51726936dbe5b1a1a7c19d303372e2a78.pdf

Comment: @DanielLitt: the link at the end of your comment is to an early version of Olsson's paper.  Did you mean to give some other link?

Comment: @nfdc23 The correct link is [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.2882.pdf).

Comment: @nfdc23: Yep, that's the paper I had in mind.  Must have copy-and-pasted the wrong URL.